# How can I perform this request using Retrofit?

Tags: retrofit2

I'm trying to perform a request using Retrofit but I'm getting 404 error whereas it is working using Postman:

- `Authorization` header with value `"key=123456789"`
- `Content-Type` header with value `application/json`

and in the body:

```
{"notification": {"title":"Title","text":"Hello"},"to":"1234"}
```

The response will be like:

```
{ "multicast_id": 108,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    { "message_id": "1:08" }
  ]
}
```

I have this Retrofit 2 code:

```
public interface FcmApi {

    @POST("/")
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: key=123456789"})
    Observable<MyResponse> send(@Body String body);

}
```

**MyResponse class**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyResponse {
    public int success;
}
```

and a test:

```
String json = "{\"notification\": " +
                "{\"title\":\"Title\",\"text\":\"Hello\"}," +
                "\"to\":\"1234\"}";
api.send(json);
```

But I get 404 error. Using Postman works properly with the same example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using key=123456789. You should be using the server key from Firebase Console. Also "to":"1234" should be the real Firebase Registration Id from your device.

Comment: Youre using Retrofit and sending message from Android or Java-based server?

Comment: From Android to Android. Vía FCM REST API

Comment: Does Retrofit provide you any debug output? i.e. what responses are received?

Comment: Just 404 bad request. I make definitely the same request in postman and it works. So I guess is due to request definition with retrofit is wrong but I dont see it.

Comment: Did you compare plain request that retrofit produces with the one that Postman produces?

Comment: How can I see the retrofit raw request?

Comment: You Need to enable Logging in Retrofit - you can easily find that on StackOverflow. Then you'll see the raw output of what Retrofit transfers